# Do anything on post_status change

Tags: posts, actions, post-status

What would be the nicest way to execute any code on `post_status` change. In our case we need execute a function the moment the `post_status` changes from `draft` to `publish`. As far as I can find there is nog action to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong search terms, already found it:

```
function on_all_status_transitions( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $new_status != $old_status ) {
        // A function to perform actions any time any post changes status.
    }
}
add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'on_all_status_transitions', 10, 3 );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: Also there is `post_updated` hook, which passes 3 arguments: post id, post after update and post before update [https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3482](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3482)